# How to group items by difference in percent in Polars?

Tags: python-polars

I'd like to group values so that the difference between each group item remains within a certain percentage. E.g. each time when an item is 5% over the first group element it goes to the new group. As a return I need the first group value. Example with 5% threshold where 'a' is given, 'group' and 'groupFirst' must be calculated:

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [100, 103, 105, 106, 105, 104, 103, 106, 100, 102],
    'group': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
    'groupFirst': [100, 100, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 100, 100]})
print(df)

shape: (10, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ a   ┆ group ┆ groupFirst │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64        │
╞═════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 100 ┆ 0     ┆ 100        │
│ 103 ┆ 0     ┆ 100        │
│ 105 ┆ 1     ┆ 105        │
│ 106 ┆ 1     ┆ 105        │
│ ... ┆ ...   ┆ ...        │
│ 103 ┆ 1     ┆ 105        │
│ 106 ┆ 1     ┆ 105        │
│ 100 ┆ 2     ┆ 100        │
│ 102 ┆ 2     ┆ 100        │
└─────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: reproducible example please?

Comment: I'm guessing a is the only real given and that group and groupFirst are what you want to achieve solely based on a? If that's the case then is the idea that the first row is groupFirst by default and then on each subsequent row if a>1.05*groupFirst then it becomes a new group?

Comment: yes, thats right

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to reset cummax when your values exceed the value `6`. You could do:

```py
(
    df.with_columns(
        (pl.col("a") >= 6)
        .shift(1)
        .fill_null(False)
        .cumsum()
        .alias("group")
    ).with_columns(
        pl.col("a")
        .cummax()
        .over(pl.col("group"))
        .alias("cummax")
    )
)
```

Example:

```py
In [73]: df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 5, 6, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 6]})

In [74]: (
    ...:     df.with_columns(
    ...:         (pl.col("a") >= 6)
    ...:         .shift(1)
    ...:         .fill_null(False)
    ...:         .cumsum()
    ...:         .alias("group")
    ...:     ).with_columns(
    ...:         pl.col("a")
    ...:         .cummax()
    ...:         .over(pl.col("group"))
    ...:         .alias("cummax")
    ...:     )
    ...: )
Out[74]:
shape: (10, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ group ┆ cummax │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ u32   ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0     ┆ 1      │
│ 3   ┆ 0     ┆ 3      │
│ 5   ┆ 0     ┆ 5      │
│ 6   ┆ 0     ┆ 6      │
│ ... ┆ ...   ┆ ...    │
│ 3   ┆ 1     ┆ 4      │
│ 6   ┆ 1     ┆ 6      │
│ 5   ┆ 2     ┆ 5      │
│ 6   ┆ 2     ┆ 6      │
└─────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Comment: close to what I need but how to get >= 106% of the first group value instead of >=6

Comment: reproducible example with expected output please

Comment: I've revised my initial question and added an example

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to use polars expressions to generate the groups since they always rely on the previous group.  That being said the groups can be easily generated in O(n) so the penalty for doing that in python should be minor.

```
import numpy as np
def make_groups(a, threshold=1.05):
    a=np.array(a)
    outarray=np.empty(len(a), dtype=a.dtype)
    outarray[0]=0
    curgroup=a[0]
    for indx, cur_a in enumerate(a[1:],1):
        if cur_a >= threshold * curgroup or cur_a * threshold <= curgroup:
            outarray[indx] = outarray[indx-1] + 1
            curgroup=cur_a
        else:
            outarray[indx] = outarray[indx-1]
    return pl.Series(outarray)
```

So now let's take that to our data.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [100, 103, 105, 106, 105, 104, 103, 106, 100, 102]})
```

We just do a map (incidentally, I tried making make_groups into a np.ufunc but couldn't get it to work).

```
df \
    .with_columns(pl.col('a').map(lambda x: make_groups(x, 1.05)).alias('group')) \
    .with_columns((pl.col('a').list().over('group').arr.first()).alias('groupFirst'))

shape: (10, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ a   ┆ group ┆ groupFirst │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64        │
╞═════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 100 ┆ 0     ┆ 100        │
│ 103 ┆ 0     ┆ 100        │
│ 105 ┆ 1     ┆ 105        │
│ 106 ┆ 1     ┆ 105        │
│ ... ┆ ...   ┆ ...        │
│ 103 ┆ 1     ┆ 105        │
│ 106 ┆ 1     ┆ 105        │
│ 100 ┆ 2     ┆ 100        │
│ 102 ┆ 2     ┆ 100        │
└─────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

By the way, if you just want to use the default threshold then you can just do...

```
df \
    .with_columns(pl.col('a').map(make_groups).alias('group')) \
    .with_columns((pl.col('a').list().over('group').arr.first()).alias('groupFirst'))
```